# Creating a transparent, scrollable, flingable list without passing in a ScrollView for Android

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a platformer game for Android. However, I'm trying to overlay a transparent, scrollable list of text and (small) images in the title screen, outside of the game. Since the title screen was written in pure Java without the aid of XML, I'm looking to avoid passing in a [ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) and changing the game's activity. Normally, I would build my own scroller programmatically, but I want my users to be able to fling the list to scroll, which I would have trouble implementing. So I was wondering if there was something for me to use. Also, I was wondering how other mobile games handle scrolling objects vertically with flinging? Do they build it themselves? Unfortunately, I can't think of a good example right now.

I'm looking to make the scrollable list transparent, so I can overlay it across a background image. Here is my title screen:

[Title Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRHFs.png)

For example, when the credits button is pressed, the list will appear, overlaying an image in the background. (I haven't made the background image yet).

Sorry for the long post, or if this didn't make sense at all.

Comment: use a `GestureDetector` for detecting the fling events and `Scroller` for implementing fling itself

Comment: but actually i dont see any reason why dont you just use a `ScrollView`...

Comment: @pskink Yeah, I'm looking into that now. Just trying to learn how to stack views.

Comment: stack views? what views?

Comment: Well, I created my own titleView programmatically. Now, I'm trying to create a ScrollView and overlay it over the titleView.

Comment: `ScrollView#addView`

Comment: @pskink That's what I've been looking at. I think I can take it from here. Thanks buddy.